Computing the commutation relation in vector form
I am trying to prove the commutation relation:
$$[p^2,\frac{\vec{r}}{r}]=\frac{2}{r^2}(\hat{r}+i\hat{r}\times \vec{L}).$$
where $\vec{p}=-i\vec{\nabla}$, $\hat{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$ and $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$.
I start by using the property of commutator, $[AB,C]=[A,C]B+A[B,C]$ as:
$[\vec{p}.\vec{p},\frac{\vec{r}}{r}]=[\vec{p},\frac{\vec{r}}{r}]\vec{p}+\vec{p}[\vec{p},\frac{\vec{r}}{r}].$
I am confused in r coordinate, and there is some use of Levi civita tensor here as well. I have previously calculated commutators by using $\psi(x)$ after the commutator as general in quantum mechanics.
Can any help or hint come?

If you are used to having a function after the commutator, then add one.

Denote by $x_i$ our three coordinates and $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. Further, let $\hat x_i$ be the unit vector in the $x_i$ direction.
Then $\nabla^2=\sum_i \partial_i^2$ and
$
\partial_i^2(\hat r\psi) = (\partial_i^2\hat r)\psi + 2(\partial_i \hat r)(\partial_i\psi) + \hat r (\partial_i^2\psi)
$
so
$
[\partial_i^2,\hat r]\psi = (\partial_i^2\hat r)\psi + 2(\partial_i \hat r)(\partial_i\psi),
$
i.e.
$$
[\partial_i^2,\hat r] = \partial_i^2\hat r + 2(\partial_i \hat r)\partial_i.
$$
Now,
$$
\partial_i\hat r
= \partial_i(r^{-1}\mathbf r)
= (-r^{-2}\partial_i r)\mathbf r + r^{-1}(\partial_i\mathbf r)
= -r^{-3}x_i\mathbf r + r^{-1}\hat x_i
$$
and
$$
\partial_i^2\hat r
= -(-3r^{-4}\partial_i r)x_i\mathbf r - r^{-3}(\partial_i x_i)\mathbf r
- r^{-3} x_i(\partial_i\mathbf r) + (-r^{-2}\partial_i r)\hat x_i + r^{-1}(\partial_i\hat x_i)
\\
= \cdots
= -2 r^{-3} x_i \hat x_i + 3 r^{-4} x_i^2\hat r - r^{-2}\hat r
.
$$
Can you continue yourself?
